# get commons between two rdd's

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to spark and I am writing spark in java. I have two RDD's that I have got after reading from the Database

```
ReadConfig readConfig = ReadConfig.create(sc).withOption("p", p);    
JavaRDD<Document> rdd1 = MongoSpark.load(sc, readConfig).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY()).repartition(80);

ReadConfig readConfig1 = ReadConfig.create(sc).withOption("p", p);
JavaRDD<Document> rdd2 = MongoSpark.load(sc, readConfig1).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY()).repartition(80);  

RDD1 is JavaRDD<String> phonenumbers 
RDD2 is JavaRDD<String> phonenumbers2
```

I wanted to get all the phonenumbers2 that are in phonenumbers. I have used `rdd1.subtract(rdd2)` but this doesn't seem to work.

How would I get rdd2 list that is in rdd1.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [java intersection](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#intersection-org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD-)

```
rdd1.intersection(rdd2)
```